# How to make Java 3D jar file working on another computer?

Tags: jar, java-3d

Can we run an executable jar file containing Java3D API on a computer which has no Java3D library installed? It's not comfortable to install java3D on any computer you want to run the application. Is there a way to include everything in the jar file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample is avaiable here: Sweet Home 3D executable jar on http://www.sweethome3d.com/download.jsp. Download and look into this jar. August

Comment: I had made the jar file with Eclipse but they were not working on ther computers. Today I realized that executing the jar files by double clicking may have unexpected results. Now I can run them by usung commad line or the commands in a .bat file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, seems my problem has not been solved fully. If once I install Java3D on the machine, and then  uninstall it, my application still works. I think because the files are still in the computer. But without any installation, I get the following error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path